# php float number error

Tags: php, floating-point

I am trying to assign float value in php to variable I tried following,

```
$_web_lat=‎18.501059;
$_web_long=73.862686;

echo $_web_lat .'='. $_web_long;

[Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.501059' (T_DNUMBER)]
```

OR

```
$_web_lat=floatval('‎18.501059');
$_web_long=floatval('‎‎73.862686');

echo $_web_lat .'='. $_web_long;
```

Both shows 0 as output?
Anyone guide me on this?

Comment: What is your version of php? `phpinfo();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code seems to have a hidden character ?

Try copy and use this:

```
<?php
$_web_lat=18.501059;
$_web_long=73.862686;

echo $_web_lat .'='. $_web_long;

?>
```

Comment: @urban Can you let me know how can I check with `vi` and what is `vi`?

Comment: The hidden character is before the 18, I see this in php fiddle.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this? in my code there is no space/char but it shows error

Comment: I'm using programmer's notepad. I copied and pasted your code to it, and saw the hidden character that is not visible in your code.

Comment: @SKIRT You need to copy past the script from this answer, it will be functional

Comment: @AyazShahI I am running Linux. `vi` is a terminal editor. I have copy/pasted the code snippet into a file using `nano`. `nano` does not display such characters but opening with `vi` does

Comment: Copy your codes into http://phpfiddle.org/ and its editor will show extra characters for both of your code snippets. What editor are you using?

Comment: tried in phpfiddle.org and it shows...how come this char added? ..really surprised..But thanks for your help

Comment: I'm using programmer's notepad. The OP uses codelobster.

Comment: great catch though

Answer (score 0):

Try to write floating values like

```
<?php

    $_web_lat=floatval('‎18.501059f');
    $_web_long=floatval('‎‎73.862686f');


$float_value_of_var1 = floatval($_web_lat);
$float_value_of_var2 = floatval($_web_long);

echo $float_value_of_var1; // 18.501059
echo $float_value_of_var2; // ‎‎73.862686

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the sintax error is caused  by automatic string conversion do the string operator `.` (dot concat)
if you want avoid this you could use or cast float value ast string

```
  $_web_lat=‎18.501059;
  $_web_long=73.862686;

  echo (string) $_web_lat .'='. (string>$_web_long;
```